# Calling a Protocol Function from A Selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, delegation

I have a protocol that acts as a delegate between one view and another.

The protocol looks (something like) this:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func functionOne()
}
```

And the protocol is implemented in `View2` with something like:

```
extension View2:MyProtocol {
    func functionOne() {
        print("Hello World"
    }
}
```

Now I want this method to be called by the target of a button in `View1`. Therefore in `View1` I have a line:

```
myButton(self, action: #selector(delegate?.functionOne), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

But the button line errors with `"Use of unresolved identifier 'functionOne'"`, which is an error I haven't seen before in other questions.

Everything works if I make a `functionTwo` in `View1` and set the target to `functionTwo`, and then implement `functionTwo` by directly calling `delegate?.functionOne`. But that seems very inelegant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2.2 #selector in protocol extension compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184912/swift-2-2-selector-in-protocol-extension-compiler-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@objc
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func functionOne()
}


button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyProtocol.functionOne), for: .touchUpInside)
```

The above syntax doesn't care where the protocol is implemented. It only cares about the name of the function and its signature. Because of this behaviour, we say `MyProtocol.functionOne` and that tells it enough. Some class conforms to that and implements a function with that signature and name.

Comment: Please note that you will crash if `self` does _not_ implement `functionOne`.

Comment: @matt wait, "if `self` does not implement `functionOne`"? Don't you mean if the `MyProtocol` class doesn't implement `functionOne`? The whole point of using delegation is that `self` purposefully does not implement `functionOne`.

Comment: I don't care about delegation. I'm just cautioning you to be careful. You are saying "send functionOne message to self". So self must be have a functionOne implementation or you will crash when that happens. Try it and see.

Comment: just replace  target value (self) with your implementation of protocol (delegate)